# Material will not assign to selected vertices

Tags: materials

My material will not assign to the selected vertices. I pressed the assigned button, but it still isn't working.

Comment: You can't assign a material to vertices or rather it won't work/show, make sure that the vertices you have selected form a _face_ or look into vertex colors.

Comment: @iKlsR All of the vertices form a face. You can see the uv mapping when you move it too. But when I select the vertices, and then assign them, it doesn't work because when I hit select it selects the whole object instead of the selected area.

Comment: Mind uploading this file or adding some images.

Comment: @KeshaWilson the first material is assigned to the whole object by default, you'll have to unassign first

Comment: @Chebhou you unassign by deselecting right?

Comment: @KeshaWilson no you have to add another slot and assign to the new one

Comment: @iKlsR Sorry but I will have to upload a photo later because the wireless part of my internet box is acting up. I will upload as soon as possible.

Comment: @Chebhou Okay adding a new material worked just fine. Thanks, guess you should answer the question now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first material is assigned to the whole object by default , to un-assign some faces from this material you'll have to :

- create another material slot ( with a material )
- assign these faces to the new material slot